# Web Deploy using Visual Studio: can publish only individual files

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core, webdeploy, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to deploy an application to a remote IIS using Web Deploy and Visual Studio. I'm only able to push individual files, but when I try publishing entire project it quickly says it was successful but pushes nothing. It builds the output to the directory, but it never copies it to the server.

Also, when I try to publish wwwroot folder it complains of another thing, that doesn't give much:

```
"Could not connect to the remote computer using the specified process ("Web      Management Service") because the server did not respond. Make sure that the process ("Web Management Service") is started on the remote computer.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC. The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."*
```

*The Web Management Service is running on the remote machine.

I'm using:

IIS version is 8.5, Webdeploy 3.6, Visual Studio 2015.
The application is a .NET Core app.

Comment: Did you follow the documentation on it? https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis-with-msdeploy.html

Comment: Thank you, what missing was changing 1.0.1 to 1.0.2-beta2 in the publish module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the doc of "Publishing an ASP.NET Core project to an IIS server" (https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis-with-msdeploy.html)

There was one additional step missed:

In the publish PowerShell script generated (under PropertiesPublishProfiles) update the publish module version number from 1.0.1 to 1.0.2-beta2. After changing 1.0.1 to 1.0.2-beta2 you can use the Visual Studio publish dialog to publish and preview changes.